# makefile include by parsing variable

Tags: makefile

This is one simple thing, and I am already spending too much time searching for solution...

I have variable in my makefile

```
$(targets): target1.o target2.o target3.o
```

Now I want to perform `include` command for target1.d target2.d target3.d based on this variable, what is the correct one-liner command to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
targets_obj := target1.o target2.o target3.o
$(targets): $(targets_obj)
-include $(targets_obj:.o=.d)
```

Comment: is there no way without adding target_obj?

Comment: It's only possible to get the list of target's prerequisites in its rule using automatic variables `$<`, `$^`, etc.., but make can't include inside a rule. Hence there need to be a variable with a list of files.

Comment: Note `-` in front of the include. It means _don't fail if `.d` files don't exist_.